# get_post_types - exclude multiple post types by name

Tags: custom-post-types, post-type

I am trying to get an array of all the post types except for `attachments` and `pages`. I've been able to do this with one exclusion like this:

```
get_post_types(
    array(
        'name' => 'page',
        'public' => false
    ),
    'names',
    'not')
);
```

This returns all post types except for `page` as expected. However, I can't seem to get it to work if I try to exclude multiple `names`. I figured I could just pass in an array like this:

```
get_post_types(
    array(
        'name' => array('page','attachment'),
        'public' => false
    ),
    'names',
    'not')
);
```

But this doesn't exclude either of the post types I am trying to exclude. Any ideas?

Comment: what are you doing with the result of the function? It may be trivial to do this by just skipping or removing the post types you don't want from the array and making no changes to `get_post_type` args at all. You don't have to do it all via the arguments

Comment: @TomJNowell I am using it for my `post_type` query arg to query all posts regardless of post type. I would prefer to generate it dynamically so as not to have to modify it whenever a new post type is added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query args you're passing to `get_post_types()` are handled by the underlying function [`wp_filter_object_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_filter_object_list/), which isn't designed to handle advanced querying operations like "if key value (not) in array".

Since you're just getting the names of post types, use the native PHP function [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to filter the out the ones you don't want:

```php
$post_types = array_diff( get_post_types(), [ 'page', 'attachment' ] );
```

FWIW, if you were getting post type *objects*, you could use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with something like:

```php
$post_type_objects = array_filter( get_post_types( [], 'objects' ), function ( $post_type_object ) {
    return ! in_array( $post_type_object->name, [ 'page', 'attachment' ] );
});
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much!